# How do I get the character pointers out of the argument array passed to my thread function?

Tags: c, pointers, pthreads

I can't figure out how to access the character pointers contained in args.  args is an array of character points that was passed into pthread_create.  Should I store the arguments in a struct instead of an array?

```
int loop(void* args){
  struct dirent *direntp; DIR *start_dir;struct stat statbuf;char *dirs[MAX_SIZE_DIRS];int error; const char* sd;
  int size = 0;
  char* fn = (char *)(args); sd = (char *)(args + 1); char* path = (char *)(args+2);
  printf("%s\n", (char *)args);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you want:

```
int loop(void* args){
  char** arr = args;
  char* fn = arr[0];
  char* sd = arr[1];
  char* path = arr[2];
```

<sup>(indeed, for readability reasons, it would have been better to declare some `struct` outside of your thread function and use an address to it, since your different elements have different roles)</sup>

You should take days to read a good C programming book before trying to code multi-threaded programs (e.g. using [POSIX threads](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/)).

BTW, the function passed to [pthread_create(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) should return a generic pointer (i.e. some `void*`), not an `int`; so your `loop` has the wrong signature to be passed to `pthread_create`. Read also about [intptr_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer)